# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Hi in my login page I have forgot password link. From where I have to send the reset password links to the users. I hope I did everything correctly, but still I am getting the " MethodNotAllowedHttpException " Error.

**HTML Code**

```
<form action="/user/sendresetlink" method="post" id="forgot_password_form" name="forgot_password_form">

    <label for="name" class="col-xs-4 control-label">User Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="user_name" name="user_name" class="form-control"  />

    <button type="submit" class="btn bg-olive btn-block">Send</button>

</form>
```

**Router Code**

```
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
```

Here I Have mentioned resource for UserController, where laravel takes care of basic CRUD routings.

```
Route::get('login', 'UserController@create');

Route::post('/user/store','UserController@store');

Route::get('logout', 'UserController@destroy');

Route::get('forgot_password','UserController@forgotPassword');

Route::post('sendresetlink','UserController@sendResetLink');
```

I have mentioned the sendresetlink as post and calling the controller. It is not even going to controller.

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('/jobs', 'JobsController@jobs_list');
});
```

**Controller Code**

```
public function sendResetLink()
{
    $form_data = Input::all();
    echo '<PRE>';
    print_r($form_data);
    exit;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Am I missing anything?

**Note:**  I have installed laravel in another machine and copied over the code to current machine. May be because of that, my php artisan is not working. When ever I tries php artisan in command prompt, it is stating that 'php' is not recognized as any internal external command. I tried to install the composer in the php.exe folder. Even then also no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At app/routes.php you have written

```
Route::post('sendresetlink','UserController@sendResetLink');
```

While at the form action you have

```
<form action="/user/sendresetlink" method="post" id="forgot_password_form" name="forgot_password_form">
```

You can fix this by changing app/routes.php to

```
Route::post('user/sendresetlink','UserController@sendResetLink');
```

There is a miss-match between your route and your form action.
**/user/** sendresetlink and just sendresetlink.

Comment: Thank you Oded Dwek. I totally missed that!

Answer (score 1):

Replace

`Route::post('sendresetlink','UserController@sendResetLink');`

With

`Route::post('/user/sendresetlink','UserController@sendResetLink');`

and it will work just fine.

**Explanation:**

Your form `action`is `<form action="/user/sendresetlink" ...`

Same should be matched with the `URL` parameter of `Route::POST` as shown above.

Comment: Thank you Mysteryous. I overlooked that! Very much appreciated your help.